# solution of variable coefficient equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the equation $$u_x + yu_y = 0$$
and I know that this PDE has solution $u(x,y) = f(e^{-x}y)$

Can someone help me to derive this PDE to get the solution? Thank you

Comment: Do you need to find the solution or want to prove the solution? (I did the easier of the two scenarios below)

Comment: Make the change of variables $z=x$ and $w=e^{-x}y$. Use the chain rule.

Comment: I want to find the solution

Comment: Now we have cleared up that mystery..Have you worked with method of charteristics?

Comment: is that the coordinate method?

Comment: yup, you can think of it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=1$ , letting $x(0)=0$ , we have $x=t$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=y$ , letting $y(0)=y_0$ , we have $y=y_0e^t=y_0e^x$

$\dfrac{du}{ds}=0$ , letting $u(0)=f(y_0)$ , we have $u(x,y)=f(y_0)=f(e^{-x}y)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x$ and $w=e^{-x}y$. This is a change of coordinates, since the jacobian is $e^{-x}\neq 0$. Also, let $v(z,w)=u(x,y)$. Then, by the chain rule,
$$
u'_x=v'_z-ye^{-x}v'_w\quad\text{and}\quad u'_y=e^{-x}v'_w.
$$
Hence,
$$
0=u'_x+yu'_y=v'_z,
$$
so $v(z,w)$ is a function of $w$ only, say $v(z,w)=f(w)$. This means that
$$
u(x,y)=v(z,w)=f(w)=f(e^{-x}y).
$$

Comment: assume that you don't know the solution is $w$. how can you let $w = e^{-x}y?$

Comment: You can use the method of characteristics to find this out. See for example this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133901/solution-to-first-order-pde-by-method-of-characteristics).